# Do cards that supply bonuses trigger on actions modified by other cards?

Tags: agricola

Many cards in Agricola give you bonus resources under certain circumstances. For example, the Stone Carrier occupation says:

> Whenever you take Stone with an
>   action, you can also take 1 additional
>   Stone. If you also receive other
>   building resources, this costs you 1
>   Food.

Many cards also modify existing actions. For example, the Quarry reads:

> Whenever you use the "Day Laborer"
>   Action, you receive an additional 3
>   Stone.

If you have a Quarry and a Stone Carrier, and you take Day Labour, do you receive 2 food and 4 stone?

Is this generally true for all cards that supply bonuses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really recommend downloading yourself a copy of the [Unofficial Agricola Companion](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/34558/the-unofficial-agricola-compendium), which has many amazingly useful and comprehensive rulings from the game designers themselves.  From the entry for Stone Carrier, for example:

- Is activated when you use an action space on which stone is placed each round. You cannot use such an action space just to use this card if the action space contains no stone (e.g. when you have the Bureaucrat.)
- Is activated by the action space "Take 1 Building Resource" in 3-player games if you take stone.
- Is also activated by the action space "1 Reed, Stone, and Wood" in 5-player games and the action space "1 Reed, Stone, and Food" in 4-player games, if you pay 1 food.
- You also pay 1 food to use this card if you receive other building resources at the same time from occupations and minor improvements.
- **Is not activated when you receive stone because of a minor improvement or occupation.**
- Other building resources are wood, clay, and reed.

I've highlighted the part that answers your question: you only get the additional Stone if you take Stone from one of the specified action spaces.  (Yes, this is generally true in Agricola, though be sure to read the card wordings carefully, and check the rulings if you are in any doubt whatsoever, as it is a game with lots of exceptions to any given rule!)

Answer (score 0):

The way I read that, you're not directly taking stone with the action.  Day Laborer gives two food only, so I don't think Stone Carrier applies in this case.  So with the Quarry, you get 2 food and 3 stone.

If you were using the family variant of Day Laborer which gives 1 food and 1 resource, then things might be different.  If you chose stone as your resource, then I think both cards apply.  You get 1 extra stone per the Stone Carrier, 3 extra stone with the Quarry, and you pay the 1 food because you received additional resources.  So I think that's a total of 5 stone and 0 food.